# How do I automate nightly disk imaging?

Tags: backup, automation, clone, clonezilla, disk-image

I do a lot of development work, and sometimes this means messing around with drivers, non-official packages, and boot settings.

I want to start automating nightly disk imaging so no matter what happens, I can always fall back to a previous image.

**Rationale**

I want to be able to mess around with by boot and grub settings to get them right, but I have once accidentally set my computer to an non-bootable state before, and I had to rescue it before, and I want to avoid rescuing it again.

Also, later I have to deploy the software I developed and it would be easy to copy images I created.

**What I have done so far**

I've taken images using a live Clonezilla usb stick, but now I want to automate the process, preferably to a network location.

I seem to have difficulty finding open-sourced solutions on Google on the level I can understand.  Does anyone else have any experience automating disk imaging?

Comment: disk images are huge files and IMO inefficinet. With what you are doing, I would highly suggest a virtual machine with snapshots.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need real time image processing for my application, which means a CUDA card.  Unless there is a way to enable CUDA in a VM.  I would not be opposed to incremental daily backups and weekly images.

Answer (score 1):

you could set up a cron script to run this (if /dev/sdd is the external image backup drive):

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdd
```

That will copy the image of /dev/sda (first HDD/SDD/USB/ETC) onto /dev/sdd (fourth HDD/SDD/USB/ETC)

Comment: If you are going to do that ... First, you will get errors with this method if you try to restore the image, second you will miss any changes written to disk while dd is running and third, at a minimum, I would compress the images.

Comment: dd makes me nervous with its potential of destroying my disc.  Also to bodhi.zazen, what kind of errors would I get?

Comment: If the disk is in use when you use dd, then at a minimum dd will not be a replica of the image. In addition you are going to image any removable media and get errors when accessing virtual kernel files. dd is , IMO, best used from a live CD with the partition you are imaging (or disk) unmounted and not in use.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, dd is not an option?

Comment: If you're messing around with stuff that messes up booting, then just `dd` the boot partition.

Comment: Like this if your boot partition is `/dev/sda1`:  `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=boot.img`.  That will output to an image file instead of a whole drive, and is much smaller: only about 100Mb.  If you wanted to compress it, then you could pipe the output of `dd` into `gzip` or some other compression program.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of research, I found my best answer to be Mondo Rescue.  It has the ability to [bootable images while the system is running](http://www.mondorescue.org/docs/mondorescue-howto.html#OVERVIEW-MONDORESCUE) (although I still need to test this).

Another possibility is the [FOG Project](https://www.fogproject.org/).  It's a network imaging management tool that can wake up computers and image them over the network.  The only downside for me is that the computers would have to be off for the server to take images.